# Defining $\{a_i\}$ as $(1+x+⋯+x^k)^n =\sum_{i=0}^{kn}a_ix^i$, then is the 'special' difference-sequence $\{d^Na_i\}$ a unimodal sequence?

Tags: number-theory

**Question** : Letting $k,n$ be positive integers, let's define a sequence $\{a_i\}\ (i=0,1,\cdots, kn)$ as
$$(1+x+\cdots+x^k)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{kn}a_ix^i.$$
Then, is the 'special' difference-sequence $\{d^Na_i\}$ a unimodal sequence  for every non-negative integer $N$? If the answer is yes, then prove that. If the answer is no, then find a counterexample.

In the following, I'm going to define some words.

*1.*  Let's call a sequence $\{a_i\}\ (i=0,1,\cdots, kn)$ which satisfies the following condition **'a unimodal sequence '**.

**Condition** : $\ $There exists an integer $t$ such that 
$$a_0\le a_1\le \cdots\le a_t\ge a_{t+1}\ge a_{t+2}\ge\cdots.$$

*2.*  Let's define $\{d^Na_i\}\ (N\in\mathbb N)$ as the following:

$$d^Na_i=\max(d^{N-1}a_i-d^{N-1}a_{i-1},0)\ \ \ (i=0,1,\cdots, kn),$$
$$d^0a_i=a_i, \ a_{-1}=0.$$

Please note that this is **not** an usual difference-sequence. (we may call this **'a special difference-sequence'**)

In the following, I'm going to write why I'm interested in this question.

When I saw Pascal's triangle, I found the following property about $a_i=\ _nC_i$. Note that this is the $k=1$ case of the above question.

For example, let's see the $n=8$ case. 
$$a_i(=d^0a_i) : 1\ \ 8\ \ 28\ \ 56\ \ 70\ \ 56\ \ 28\ \ 8\ \ 1$$

$$d^1a_i : 1\ \ 7\ \ 20\ \ 28\ \ 14\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

$$d^2a_i : 1\ \ 6\ \ 13\ \ 8\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

$$d^3a_i : 1\ \ 5\ \ 7\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

$$d^4a_i : 1\ \ 4\ \ 2\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

$$d^5a_i : 1\ \ 3\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

$$d^6a_i : 1\ \ 2\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

$$d^7a_i : 1\ \ 1\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

$$d^Na_i (N\ge 8): 1\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0\ \ 0$$

Hence, we can see that $\{d^N{_8C_i}\}\ (i=0,1,\cdots,8)$ is a unimodal sequence  for every non-negative integer $N$.

Then, I reached an expectation, which is the above question. The answer seems yes, but I'm facing difficulty. I need your help.

*Update* : I crossposted to MO.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142565/about-the-unimodality-of-the-coefficients-sequence-of-1x-cdotsxkn

Comment: What you call single-peak sequence is called [unimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality) sequence in the literature. Using that term might attract a proper audience (and help find information about it).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Thank you. I edited them.

Comment: I suspect that there would exist some papers which are helpful. Could anyone please tell me whether the following papers are helpful?
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316504001153

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Zeilberger590-602.pdf

http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/JACO/Volume7_1/lq570788673x17gl.fulltext.pdf

http://www.math.miami.edu/~wachs/papers/unimodal.pdf

Comment: I think your main difficulty is that your difference operator is quite unusual (the usual one does not cut off negative values) and the property you want to prove clearly fails if you take the usual definition of the difference operation. This means that most theory you will find will not apply to your problem statement.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I know this is unusual, but I would like to know this. Anyway, thanks always.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: One reason why I use this difference operator is to keep the unimodality; If I define ${\Delta}^N a_i$ as ${\Delta}^{N-1}a_i-{\Delta}^{N-1}a_{i-1}$ as usual, then ${\Delta}^1a_i$ will be $1,7,20,28,14,-14,-20,-7$ which is not unimodal in my above example. Anyway, I'm interested in this question.

Comment: Perhaps it is a better way to express $(1+x+x^2+...+x^k)^2$ as an outer-product of the vector $[1,1,1,...1]$ with itself and then see that the coefficients $a_k$ are the sums of the antidiagonals (the Cauchyproduct) where the number of summands is obvious. Then to repeat the argument either by $((1+x+x^2+...+x^k)^2)^2$, which is simple but must then be done for the missing cases, or by induction of $(1+x+x^2+...+x^k)^n \to (1+x+x^2+...+x^k)^(n+1)$ I think the second path might be more promising...

Comment: The current title, though concise, is confusing, since it does not address the essence of the question. That $(1+x+\cdots+x^k)^n$ is unimodal (and log concave) is a consequence of standard results about unimodal/log concave sequences. The application of finite differences is a huge complication.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Thank you very much for pointing it out.

Comment: Your sequence also (obviously?) depends on $k$; you should make that dependence explicit somewhere in the question, I think.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Well, it seems obvious, I think. Anyway, I added a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by David Speyer on MO.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142565/defining-a-i-as-1xxkn-sum-i-0kna-ixi-then-is-the-speci

He uses Descartes' rule of signs.